# What is the cost to store 1kB, 10kB, 100kB worth of data into the Solana blockchain?

Tags: data-storage

How does one store 1kB, 10kB, or 100kB of arbitrary data/text in the Solana blockchain?

How much would this cost exactly at today's prices?

Comment: You should only really have one question per post as per general SO guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solana CLI command:

```
solana rent bytes
```

Here are some numbers for your storage:

[image]